# Where and how should SVG filters be defined in an html document?

Tags: css, svg, svg-filters

I'm referencing some SVG filters in a class definition all within an html document as shown below...

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html lang="en">
<head>
<svg>

<filter id="red" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB" x="0" y="0" height="100%" width="100%">
<feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0" />
</filter>

</svg>
<style>

.red {blend-mode:lighten; mix-blend-mode:lighten; opacity:1; -webkit-filter:url(#red); filter:url(#red);}

</style>

</head>
.......etc..
```

This has the effect that I'm looking for in Firefox, causes Chrome to struggle and then crash.  My web page does not work at all (white screen) on iphone safari.

Have I defined and placed the SVG correctly and in the correct place.  Or have is there something wrong in the way the class style is defined?

Comment: Don't put the svg in the head. Put it at the top of the body. You can give this svg a very small size and/or `display none` https://css-tricks.com/ is putting the definitions svg at the bottom of their site, just above the scripts, and the style for this svg is `position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;`

Comment: If Chrome crashes you [should report it](http://dev.chromium.org/for-testers/bug-reporting-guidelines)

Comment: Thanks enxaneta.  That answers my question, but does not resolve the problem with the page not running on the iphone.  A little more research and it appears that the iphone safari does not yet support svg and css blending, and certainly not to <DIV>s which is what I'm doing.